BLUERT evaluation metric consumed too much RAM
The BLEURT codes almost used up all the 24GB RAM of NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 to evaluate just 1 set of sentences.
ref = 'reference sentence here'
hypo = 'hypothesis sentence here'

scores = {}
import evaluate
metric_bleurt = evaluate.load('bleurt')
bleurt = metric_bleurt.compute(predictions=[hypo], references=[ref])
scores["bleurt"] = round(bleurt["scores"][0], 3)
print(scores)

Total memory spent is 22290MB. How is that possible? How do I reduce memory usage when evaluating BLEURT? Thanks

To reduce the memory usage try to set a lower value for bleurt_batch_size. To speed up on a machine with GPU it uses a value of 100, you could try a lower value.

Thanks, but how could I add this flag using evaluate library? In the original GitHub, it did mention about this flag, but seems it cannot be used with the evaluate library.

I use metric_bleurt = evaluate.load('bleurt', bleurt_batch_size=2), but still 22290MB RAM is used.

If the BLEURT model is large it requires a considerable amount of VRAM to load and run. You have to use a smaller version of the model.

The default model is bleurt-tiny (please read this), in theory it is the smallest one.

You could do the batch processing yourself computing small batches of the references and hypotheses until all are done and keep the scores in a list.

But I work on just 1 set of hypothesis and reference only...
